# iBatis unable to read property from Map when using isEqual

Tags: ibatis

I'm seeing a very bizarre issue with iBatis when trying to read a property from a Java map using `isEqual`, but not with other iBatis operators. For example it is able to read the map properties fine when using `isNotNull` and `iterate`. The xml:

```
    <isNotNull property="filterCriteria.account">
        AND
        id
        <isEqual property="filterCriteria.account.meetsCriteria" compareValue="false">
            NOT
        </isEqual>
        IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM account
        WHERE some other criteria....
        )
    </isNotNull>
```

The 2 java classes we're using here:

```
public class SearchProfile {

private Map<String, SearchProfileCriteria> filterCriteria;

public SAOSearchProfile() {
    filterCriteria = new HashMap<>();
}

public Map<String, SAOSearchProfileCriteria> getFilterCriteria() {
    return filterCriteria;
}

public void setFilterCriteria(Map<String, SAOSearchProfileCriteriaBase> filterCriteria) {
    this.filterCriteria = filterCriteria;
}

}
```

Above is the container object that is passed to iBatis for the querying, and below is the criteria object that will be the value of the map. In this example it is keyed with the String `"account"`

```
public class SearchProfileCriteria {

boolean meetsCriteria;

public String getCriteriaAsString() {
    return StringUtils.getStringValueFromBoolean(meetsCriteria);
}

public boolean isMeetsCriteria() {
    return meetsCriteria;
}

public void setMeetsCriteria(boolean meetsCriteria) {
    this.meetsCriteria = meetsCriteria;
}

public String getSQLString(){
    return meetsCriteria ? "" : "NOT";
}
}
```

And the exception:

```
Cause: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named 'account' in class 'java.util.Map'; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
```

The `getSQLString()` method was my half baked attempt at a work around, the String gets escaped in the query and throws a syntax error.

When I remove the `<isEqual>` block the query executes find, which indicates it is able to read the `"account"` key when checking the to see if it is null. As I mentioned above, we're also able to use the map keys in `<iterate>` tags without issue. It seems `<isEqual>` and `<isNotEqual>` are the only tags causing issues. Does anyone have experience with this or know what may be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Beware: Using `isNotNull`, `isEqual`, `iterate` is **iBatis**, they don't exist anymore in **Mybatis**, so referencing to Mybatis indifferently is confusing.

[Reference documentation](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/java/pdf/iBATIS-SqlMaps-2_en.pdf).

For your issue, how does it behave if replacing Map with a class (property will be known at compile time)?

Or try using `<isPropertyAvailable>`.

The work around could work with right syntax: `$` instead of `#`: `$filterCriteria.account.SQLString$` instead of `#filterCriteria.account.SQLString#`, then the value is just concatenated instead of bound as parameter.